# can't get ScrollMagic parralax tween to work

Tags: scrollmagic

I'm trying to implement the code from the first example here:

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/advanced/parallax_scrolling.html

The following tween works (but tweens immediately)...

```
var tween = new TimelineMax().add([
        TweenMax.to('#test',1,{top:"50%",ease:Linear.easeNone})
    ]);
```

When I add the following code...

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement:'#test' ,
    duration:500
})
    .setTween(tween)
    .addTo(controller);
```

I get the below error:

`Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).setTween is not a function`

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering my own question since god the documentation for this thing is sparse.

You need to include

`http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js`

to make scrollmagic work with gsap

tips: make sure you added it after `ScrollMagic.js` script tag

Comment: Correct. By the way: This is something ScrollMagic even notifies you about if you use the uncompressed version instead of the minified one. Always use the uncompressed version during development.

Comment: And here is minified version: `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js`